using meson to build Cython with dependency on C++ template
I have a Cython file wrapping a C++ template, similar to this example. Previously I used this setup.py to create a .so file that could be accessed from Python:
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension("my_module", ["lib_wrapper.pyx"],
                         include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
                         extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11", "-O1"],
                         language="c++")]

setup(
    name='name',
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules
)

How to reproduce the same result with meson.build? This example produced .so.p file, which did not work for me...

Here is a minimal example for a meson.build file:
project(
  'purelib-and-platlib',
  'cpp',
  'cython',
  version: '0.1',
  default_options: [
    # https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html#core-options
    'warning_level=2',
    'cpp_std=c++14',
    'buildtype=release', # for -O3
  ],
)

py = import('python').find_installation()
py.extension_module(
  'lib_wrapper', # Target name
  ['lib.cpp', 'lib_wrapper.pyx'], # Source files
  override_options: ['cython_language=cpp'],
)

Then follow the tutorial of meson-python if your file is included in a whole package. Otherwise  meson setup build and meson compile -C build will create all the files you need in the build folder. (the module you want is lib_wrapper.<smthing>.<ext>).
